# Creat UI Application from Console Application

Tags: c#, user-interface, console

I have a Console application which is very good, I want to popularize it, but that is difficult to use because there is no user interface to interact smoothly. So I want to make an UI program for it. That is creating an application with user-interface to control the rigidity for the Console.
How to do it?

Comment: which programming language? which os? ... what have you tried so far? ...

Comment: there are still many possibilities to achieve this. you could write an application that builds and call commands like `your-console-app --option1 --option2` or you can build all in one app and have an option for starting it with a gui like `your-app --gui`... there are so many posibilities. maybe you research a bit for yourself and come back when you have questions on a specific topic or a specific problem. greetings.

Comment: how to handler a console application using c#?

Comment: i am not a c# programmer. but try this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx there is an overloaded version of `start` which takes 2 string params, an applikation (your commandline app) and one for the parameters.

Comment: thanks you, I will try.

Comment: @giaosudauto Have you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to be a little more specific than that, if we are to be able to help you. It might be helpful if you specify the platform or language that you used to develop the console application. And keep in mind that Console applications work more simpler than usual GUI applications. But the general purpose can be recreated.

On that note, I'll mention two of many tools that can be used to create GUI apps.

1. Qt (Cross-Platform)
2. Visual Studio (Windows)

If you use C#, I assume that you selected the console application option in Visual studio. You can use the WPF project in Visual Studio to do the same in GUI. How to do it might depend on the console application.

[image]

To learn more about WPF, you may try http://www.wpftutorial.net/HelloWPF.html

Comment: thanks, i want make UI application to control console application availability. How to do? could you give some keyword to search??